# $ n \le \sigma(n) \le n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how to prove:
$$ n \le \sigma(n) \le n^2$$

$\sigma(n)$ is summation of all of positive divisors $n$

Comment: For the second inequality, $$\sum_{d\mid n}d\le\sum_{d\mid n}n\le\sum_{1\le d\le n}n.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n \leq \sigma(n)$ follows from the fact that $n$ divides itself.

No integer greater than $n$ divides $n$, and the sum of the first $n$ positive integers is less than or equal to $n^2$. That is, even if all positive integers less than or equal to $n$ were divisors of $n$, their sum would be less than or equal to $n^2$. From this, it follows that $\sigma(n) \leq n^2$.

Combining the two inequalities, we get $n \leq \sigma(n) \leq n^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What's the largest divisor of $n$?